# Android Activity and Bluetooth Service killed in background

Tags: android, mobile, service, background, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Android app activity binds to a service, which connects to a BLE peripheral and receives data. It does this until the user presses a button on the activity to disconnect from the peripheral and stop the service.

Sometimes after running with the screen locked for about ~45 minutes+ the activity and service are terminated. My conclusion was that Android 8.1 was more aggressive than previous operating systems, so I changed the background service to a foreground service, and made sure that once the peripheral is connected I stop scanning.

This didn't work, and every now and then my app is killed in the background, and I don't think it is an uncaught exception. I have read the Android docs on Services and the Application Lifecycle and have added some debugging logs into lifecycle callbacks, which hasn't helped. I have observed this behaviour on Huawei Y5 and Nokia 8 running Android 8.1 - I don't remember it being an issue on an older phone which I no longer have.

I have a few questions about behaviour that aren't clearly documented that might help me figure out this issue. Thanks for your help!

```
1. If an activity is killed in the background and it is bound to a service, will that kill the service?

2. If a service is killed in the background, will that kill my activity

3. If there are multiple services running and one consumes too many resources, does the OS kill everything, or just the misbehaving service?

4. What sort of things makes an activity or service a target for the OS? Holding on to wakelocks permanently? BLE scanning? Receiving too many BLE packets? Uploading too much data? Any insight here about what might be happening under the hood is appreciated.

5. Does having the phone on charge prevent the OS from killing apps? I believe it occurs in my case regardless.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for Android to kill.your activity. Therefore it is not a good idea to setup you bluetooth in an activity. Set it up in a  seperate class or in your Application class and use other ways to send data to your activity, e.g. broadcasting. That way it will keep working even if your Activity is killed or recreated.

Is your application really being killed or is it just your Activiry that is killed?